# Генерация заголовков

Tags: javascript, html

> Программа с интервалом в 2 сек случайным образом создает 10 заголовков
> `(h1, h2` или `h6`) и помещает внутрь текст
>
> > ‘Я заголовок `h${n}`’.
>
> Важно! Каждый вновь создаваемый заголовок не должен находится выше
> заголовка с меньшим именем. Т.е. заголовок h3 на странице не может
> быть выше `h2` -

Это полное условие задачи.
Вообще не понимаю как это решать кто-то можете полностью весь код написать?

Мои попытки:

```
let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
let h2 = document.createElement("h2");
let h6 = document.createElement("h6");

let g = setInterval(() => {
  let rand = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  console.log(rand);
}, 2000);

h1.textContent = "hello";
console.log(h1);
console.log(h2);
console.log(h6);
```

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки сделать это

Comment: @SwaD Я внес изменения

Comment: Нет, так не пойдет... Это не попытка. Ни одного вывода данных на страницу(консоль не считаетя).

Comment: @SwaD так я не понимаю как сделать это попытка была самая первая были еще но не чего не выходило

Comment: Отложи в сторону компьютер и возьми бумажку. Напиши для себя алгоритм, как бы ты это делал вручную. После увидишь закономерности и повторения. А уже потом переноси это в код. Подскажу - тебе надо использовать массив для хранения результата итогового.

Comment: @SwaD честно не чего не понял я новичок еще только учусь спрашивал у одногрупников нечем не помогли

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
function test(n) {
  const t = 'H' + (Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1)
  const o = document.createElement(t)
  o.textContent = 'Я заголовок №' + n
  const ob = document.querySelector('body')
  const op = [...ob.childNodes].reduceRight((o, e) => {
    if (o) return o
    const val = e.tagName ?? ''
    if (val[0] === 'H' && val <= t) return e
    return null
  }, null)
  if (op) op.after(o)
  else ob.prepend(o)
  if (n++ < 10) setTimeout(test, 1000, n)
}
test(1)
```

Comment: это на чистом js ? и у тебя заголовок h9 на странице находится выше чем например h2

Comment: @Aleksandr На чистом, но преподу ты это не объяснишь. Т.е. доказать что код не твой легко)

Comment: @Aleksandr, да чистый js. Заголовка h9 не существует, это порядковые номера. Заголовки генерятся с h1 по h6...

Comment: @SwaD, до этого ТС писал де не знает как такое делать - теперь у него есть пример, может сможет чего сам...